# C# Class Function Return Class (Performance)

Tags: c#

I have created a class like this.

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    public string myProp { get; set; }

    public SimpleClass()
    {
        this.myProp = "";
    }

    public SimpleClass Method1()
    {
        this.myProp += "Method1";
        return this;
    }

    public SimpleClass Method2()
    {
        this.myProp += "Method2";
        return this;
    }

    public string GetProp()
    {
        return this.myProp;
    }
}
```

I'm using it like this.

```
public class Worker
{
    public Worker()
    {
        string Output = new SimpleClass().Method1().Method2().GetProp();
    }
}
```

All functions return the container class and last method returns result.

I'm curious about this performance, is it bad thing to use methods like for performance or good?

Should i use it like that or could you suggesst another way.

Thanks

Comment: Returning something from a method doesn't generally affect performance.  Why do you think it would?  Have you *measured* a performance problem?  I'd focus more on the clarify and semantics of the code you're writing at this point than micro-optimizing a millisecond of performance.

Comment: I just started to use it, I confused bcs of i return an object always. At the memory they are keeped as a new object or same object as first instance?

Comment: it doesn't affect on your performance but it's better to encupsolate it and hide complexity from endUser

Comment: No, this will not create any additional objects.

Comment: What you *should* be concerned about is using `+=` to do repeated string concatenation, as opposed to a `StringBuilder`, but even then, only when it's a bottleneck. If you're doing this one time at startup to build a configuration, for example, there is zero point to rewriting the code at all. As long as it's obviously correct, it's good.

Comment: I suppose too not create more additional objects, Thanks for replys.

Comment: If the output is deterministic, you might want to use a singleton pattern - it would save you the time & resources involved in creating and disposing the instance. It won't be hugely noticeable, immediately, and may never reach the level of becoming noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

some suggestion :
how should user know First Call `method1` then `Method2` and finally `GetProp()`?

It's better to encapsulate your methods and hide all Complexity. For example User just call `GetProp()` and in `GetProp()` you can Do what you want .
your exmple can change like below :

```
 public class SimpleClass
{
    public string myProp { get; set; }

    public SimpleClass()
    {
        this.myProp = "";
    }

    private string Method1()
    {
        this.myProp += "Method1";
        return Method2();

    }

    private string Method2()
    {
      return  this.myProp += "Method2";

    }

    public string GetProp()
    {
        Method1();
        return this.myProp;
    }
}
```

Finally call your Prop() Method like :

```
        SimpleClass simple = new SimpleClass();
    string Output = simple.GetProp();
```

And Another suggestion to have better Design is Make Your `Mathod1` and `Method2` as `Private`.

Comment: OP is probably writing Fluent API, there is nothing wrong about fluent design and its not confusing if its done on purpose.

Comment: also why make Method1 and 2 private? why its better design?

Comment: For this to work, they *shouldn't* be private. (Unless you are doing some non-standard stuff.)

Comment: What happen if user just call getprop()? ? The value is different with method2().getprop()

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are reinventing the wheel in wrong way. you are probably looking for `StringBuilder` which does exactly same thing.

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
var result = builder.Append("something").Append("something else").ToString();
```

but if you still want to have dedicated class to provide meaningful methods instead of just `Append` and also provide some abstraction over arguments being passed you can do this.

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    private readonly StringBuilder _builder = new StringBuilder();

    public SimpleClass Method1()
    {
        _builder.Append("Method1");
        return this;
    }

    public SimpleClass Method2()
    {
        _builder.Append("Method2");
        return this;
    }

    public string GetProp()
    {
        return _builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Note that using `StringBuilder` is efficient way of appending strings together. for small number of appends it may not show difference, but for large number of appends it will be faster and produces less garbage.